# Can't select cells in UITableView

Tags: uiview, xcode4, uitableview

I want to create a menu that appears sliding from a side of my view, so I programmatically created a UIView and a UITableView, but, when it appears I can't select the cells in my view, here's the code where I created the view and the table:

```
paintView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 400)];
[paintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];    
tablaConfig = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-160, 0, 160, 400) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tablaConfig.delegate = self;
tablaConfig.dataSource = self;
tablaConfig.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
tablaConfig.scrollEnabled = NO;
tablaConfig.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[paintView addSubview:tablaConfig];
```

And here's the code where I make the table appear and disappear:

```
- (IBAction)btnTablaConfig:(id)sender {

    if (selector) {
        if (self.view.frame.origin.x == 0) {

            //[self.view addSubview:paintView];

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

            // Move right.
            rect.origin.x += 160;
            rect.size.width -= 160;

            self.view.frame = rect;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            selector = false;
            tablaConfig.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       }

    }
    else {

        if (self.view.frame.origin.x == 160) {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // if you want to slide up the view
            CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
            rect.origin.x -= 160;
            rect.size.width += 160;

            self.view.frame = rect;
            [UIView commitAnimations];
            selector = true;
            tablaConfig.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
        //[paintView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Hope you can help

**EDIT**:

When I use this, I can select the cells, but lose the sliding effect, how can I get both?

```
- (IBAction)btnTablaConfig:(id)sender {

if (selector) {
    [self.view addSubview:tablaConfig];
    selector = false;
}
else {
    [tablaConfig removeFromSuperview];
    selector = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. But if you want the cell to be highlighted when selected, you need to add this line of code to your tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
yourcell.selectionstyle = UITableViewSelectionStyleBlue
```

You can also use UITableViewSelectionStyleGray. If you want to perform some actions when they select the row, you can use the tableviewdelegate methods:

> Managing Selections
>
> – tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
>
> – tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
>
> – tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
>
> – tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:

UITableViews can be tricky but stuff like this can be easily found in Apples references at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/

Just Search for the class or delegate or whatever you are using.

Comment: my problem is that when I try to select any cell of my table nothing happens, the code in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath doesn't get started (I've got a NSLog(@"I'm here"); but it never shows anything)

Comment: sorry, I meant didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Have you checked that your tablaconfig.allowsSelection is YES?

Comment: actually I don't get to use the property allowsSelection, but I'll give it a try

Comment: PS: When I disable the sliding I can select the cells, but, if I slide the table I can't, any suggestions to the code where i make the table appear and disappear so I can still select the cells?

Comment: Im fairly sure this has something to do with the fact that u dont add it as a subview, but i dont have the time to check any more extensively right now. Sorry for that, im on a deadline for funding ^^"

Comment: In the end I put a UITableView in my storyboard view and now it works, I'm sure it has something to do with the code, maybe some day I'll figure it out

Answer (score 2):

I also got this problem and I also didn't found that.

I am using `NIDropDown` custom control tableview shows but i cant select or scroll.
problem was that when I do `[anySuperView addSubview:anyTableView];`

My `anySuperView`'s size (75) was less than my `anyTableView`'s size (400).
so I made `superViews` size (500) and my problem solved.

Any body who can give more technical detail about this will be appreciated.

So late answering this because I found no solution anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

It had a similar problem. I solved it by adding my table view farther down down the line and setting up a flag to keep track if it was installed. In your code, move [paintView addSubview:tablaConfig]; into the btnTablaConfig: method, executing it the first time the table is expanded. The problem seems to involve view init code timings.